# Java Result Set

Tags: java, oracle

I am using Eclipse SDK 3.2.0, and I am connecting to Oracle 11g using Java.
I am using a simple JDBC connection.
I am assigning my queried data to the Result set function.
I am able to get one column at a time using rs.getstring.
How can I get all the columns printed one a time within my 'while' loop using rs.next()?

Comment: You should write your own method for this.

Comment: What is the real problem, because what I read is as simple as just retrieving all the columns inside the loop and printing them.

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
while(rs.next()) {
  for (int i = 0; i < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
    System.out.println("col-nr: %d - %s", i, rs.getString(i));
  }
}
```

Comment: Please do not spoon feed, this is not solution of answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want get all columns data. you can try ResultSetMetaData  class.

```
ResultSet rs = xxx;
ResultSetMetaData rsmd =rs.getMetadata();
```